# Reset Socket.io Client connection

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I write a Google Chrome Extension that uses Socket.io capabilities. More precisely, it's an AngularJS app with angular-socket.io on board.

I allow users to set up socket.io server address and port in the options page. Everything works fine until a user wants to change the address because I don't know how to reset the Socket.io connection. Ideally, I would like to close previous connection and reconnect with new connection without restarting the app (remember, it's an Chrome Extension, I cannot restart it by itself).

So my question is: **How to reset the Socket.io client connection and reconnect with new DSN**?

PS. I'm using socket.io-client#1.3.6

Comment: _"I cannot restart it by itself"_ Can you explain what you mean? You're probably wrong.

Comment: @Xan I meant that afaik I cannot "refresh" background page by the extension itself where my socket client script belongs. It's the only way so far to simulate connection reset.

Comment: `chrome.runtime.reload()`, though that's a blunt instrument and there should be a better way.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this but I'm afraid I've already read that's not the best way to control extension's life. However, I would like to restart only socket connection to not to stop other processes working in background :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using [angular-socket.io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io), so you inject socket.io (with a given config) as a service into your angular app. Assuming your service is called ***socketIOService*** you can do following:

- Disconnect on client-side with `socketIOService.disconnect();`
- Reconnect with `socketIOService.connect(SERVER_IP, {'force new connection': true});`